# How to get a list of all libraries in a Mac OS X's C package?

Tags: c, macos, bash, command-line, package

I am trying to get a list of all of the library files in my Mac OS X's c package, but I don't even know what the name of the package is, or how to get the files once I know the package. Are there any command-line tools that I can use to extract these files?

Comment: Do you mean `ls -R /usr/lib`? What is a "c package"?

Comment: I meant package linux's glibc or libc6. It would be the package used to install C on your computer that should have come with a mac. However, it seems like Mac doesn't have one, according to the answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac OS X does not have a “C” package that I know of. You can list the packages installed on your system with `pkgutil --packages`. You can list the files installed by a specific package, such as `com.apple.pkg.clang`, with `pkgutil --files <name of package>`.